# cannot use custom 403 error page on litespeed

Tags: centos, centos7, litespeed, directadmin

I have Litespeed and Directadmin on my server and i want to create access control with ip list and show 403 custom error to customers. I can deny all requests and allow from a IP but how can i show custom 403 error page on my litespeed ?

Comment: Try to put "ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml" in the top of your .htaccess file. And please replace 403.shtml with your real 403 custom page location in server

Comment: where is htaccess file? I can't find it

Comment: under your document root, create it if it does not exist. https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/locate-and-create-htaccess